# Exported method Benchmark_benchmark_metadata is not found

Tags: benchmarking

Upon upgrading dependencies from polkadot-v1.0.0 to polkadot-v1.3.0, we encounnter this error when we try to run benchmarks:

```
cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks
./target/release/integritee-collator benchmark pallet --list --chain integritee-rococo-local-dev
Error: Input("Did not find the benchmarking metadata. This could mean that you either did not build the node correctly with the `--features runtime-benchmarks` flag, or the chain spec that you are using was not created by a node that was compiled with the flag: Other: Exported method Benchmark_benchmark_metadata is not found")
```

the error is new and only appears in this PR:
https://github.com/integritee-network/parachain/pull/259

which depends on this branch for our custom pallets:
https://github.com/integritee-network/pallets/pull/249

we basically compared everything to the parachain-template at release-crates-io-v1.3.0

we found other answers here on SE but didn't find the solution yet

Comment: Does not build for me with `use of undeclared crate or module imp`. On commits `d516799` and `16192d`.

Comment: yes, I saw that a while ago, but it disappeared.
that actually makes me suspect feature propagation issues, but zepter is happy

Comment: Can you delete your target folder and check if the issue still appears?  
I assume maybe its not re-building the WASM? Since it looks more like a build error.  
I also see that `pallet-teerex` is enabling `test-utils` for benchmarking?  
You can check a bit with `zepter` `never-enables` or `never-implies`, but its a bit buggy. `--precondition runtime-benchmarks` or `default` and then `--stays-disabled std`.

Comment: your hint was very helpful: we indeed leaked std through test-utils. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

the problem was a combination of multiple issues:

1. cargo didn't realize changes in toml files and didn't rebuild the wasm when it should have
2. we introduced a `std` leak in our own pallets when `runtime-benchmarks` was enabled
3. zepter didn't find the std leak

Comment: Yes the Polkadot-SDK Zepter config only checks that everything that needs to be enabled is also enabled.  
It does *not* check if too much is enabled... for example like leaking std. But i can add it :)

Comment: I also think that there is a but somewhere in the WASM builder which is why it sometimes does not rebuild...